# Issue with printf on char array

Tags: c, printf, strtok

The below code is making use of the strtok method and storing the words gotten by strtok into the char * array words. I am then trying to print the words within the char * array words in reverse order. I am getting an extra word that I have no idea where it is coming from. any help?

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/* What characters are used to separate words? */
#define DELIMITERS " " 
#define MAX_SIZE 100

int main() {
 /* A simple string for illustration */
 char line[] = "seven years ago our fathers brought forth";

 /* A pointer to be used by strtok() */
 char *ptr;
 char *words[MAX_SIZE];

  printf("Before processing: \"%s\"\n", line);

  /* Find the first word in the line */
  ptr = strtok(line, DELIMITERS);

  int i = 0;
  while (ptr != NULL) {
    /* process the current word */
    /*printf("\"%s\"\n", ptr);*/

    words[i] = ptr;

    /* get the next word in the line */
    ptr = strtok(NULL, DELIMITERS);  /* NB: line is NOT the first argument! */
    i++;
  }

  /* Observe that strtok() modifies the string we have been scanning */
  printf("After processing: \"%s\"\n", line);

  int j;
  puts("Outputting words in reverse order : ");
  /* print out strings in reverse order */
  for (j = (sizeof(&words) - 1); j >= 0; j--)  {
    printf("\"%s\"\n", words[j]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
./a.out
Before processing: "seven years ago our fathers brought forth"
After processing: "seven"
Outputting words in reverse order : 
"free"
"forth"
"brought"
"fathers"
"our"
"ago"
"years"
"seven"
```

Where is free coming from??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problems is that `sizeof(&words) - 1` is wrong, because `sizeof(&words)` is the size of a pointer i.e. `sizeof(void *)` which on your platform seems to be `8` so your for loop is then

```
for (j = 7 ; j >= 0; j--)
```

since there is nothing at the eighth position in the array it's printing a garbage value, change your for loop to

```
for (j = i  - 1 ; j >= 0; j--)
```

As to why it's printing `free` that is very unpredictable, in your case it might be comming from debugging symbols in your binary file, but when reading uninitalized data the result is not predictable in my case the printed value was

```
���A�
```

which is not even printable.

Comment: Yes, but where is "free" coming from?

Comment: @NathanTuggy I assume that it's comming from debugging symbols, since you are accessing uninitialized data.

Comment: That seems plausible enough, but it would be nice to have a solid, detailed explanation for that particular symptom.

Comment: I want to know if the next word is "beer" so we can have a party. :)

Comment: How do I fix this then? I get a segmentation fault if I user just words and not &words.

Comment: @connormoore don't use that at all, if you use just `words` the `for` loop  goes like `for (j = 799 ; j >= 0 ; --i)` so in this case you will eventually access the correct place to cause a segmentation fault because in this case you are accessing the array out of bounds, see the last update on my answer.